# Convert binary to dates Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a binary like this:

```
0001111000011111111111110001011011000000000011111100000111110
```

I want to convert a range of numbers to dates starting from 01/10/2021 to 11/30/2021, knowing that each number in the range corresponds to a date.
The value 1 represents the day out and the value 0 represents the day at home.
So output:

| Day | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 01/10/2021 | 0 |
| 02/10/2021 | 0 |
| 03/10/2021 | 0 |
| 04/10/2021 | 1 |
| .... | .... |
| 30/11/2021 | 0 |

How can I do? Thank you for help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your dataframe like this:

```
code = '0001111000011111111111110001011011000000000011111100000111110'
start_date = '2021-10-01'

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': pd.date_range(start_date, periods=len(code), freq='D'),
                   'Code': list(code)})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          Day Code
0  2021-10-01    0
1  2021-10-02    0
2  2021-10-03    0
3  2021-10-04    1
4  2021-10-05    1
..        ...  ...
56 2021-11-26    1
57 2021-11-27    1
58 2021-11-28    1
59 2021-11-29    1
60 2021-11-30    0

[61 rows x 2 columns]
```